# Source scripts or certain lines of script

Tags: r, loading

I have multiple R scripts for different models and I need to make it easily accessible for other people to use. So I would like to have one script in which only contains sources to run the other scripts without people having to search through many files to find the right one. some of the scripts have more than one model in so if possible I would like to source only specific blocks of lines from those scripts.

For example to find the accuracy of ARIMA in different ways I have to run the following different scripts in turn;

- Read data
- Arima
- Accuracy of in-sample
- Accuracy out Read data
- Accuracy of out forced param
- Accuracy out sample

The amount of different scripts causes the risk of an error to be higher. especially as within 3 of those scripts is 5 other models which if running myself I would just highlight the specific model I'm wanting to use and run, but for other people that may be more confusing.

I know that I have to use `source()` to get the scripts to run but im stuck as to how to source only certain parts of the script and the correct way to source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make one code that automates the whole thing and then use `knitr` to create a word, or pdf document of the whole thing for other people to read easily?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to source parts of scripts, move these bits of code into functions, and then just call the functions you need.

Start by searching around for  how to [write R functions](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html)

You can put all your functions into a single file, source it, and then make your recipes of functions with orders for others.